# Entity Framework Code First - Deleting Column is blocked due to Foreign Key

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am trying to delete a column from my table, I deleted that COLUMN from the model class and ran the migration commands, and this SQL script got generated:

```
DECLARE @var0 nvarchar(128)

SELECT @var0 = name
FROM sys.default_constraints
WHERE parent_object_id = object_id(N'dbo.PRODUCT)
  AND col_name(parent_object_id, parent_column_id) = 'ID_PRODUCT_PARENT';

IF @var0 IS NOT NULL
   EXECUTE('ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @var0 + ']')

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT] 
    DROP COLUMN [ID_PRODUCT_PARENT]

INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]--------------------------------------------------XXXX
```

When I run the command `update-database -Verbose`, I get this error:

> The object 'FK_PRODUCT_PRODUCT' is dependent on column 'ID_PRODUCT_PARENT'.
> ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN ID_PRODUCT_PARENT failed because one or more objects access this column

I checked the table, when I expanded the keys I see `FK_PRODUCT_PRODUCT` but not sure why the SQL is not generating the script to drop this key.

How do I fix this issue? I am worried that if I drop `FK_PRODUCT_PRODUCT` manually from the table it might cause issues.

When i tried right clicking the the key FK_PRODUCT_PRODUCT and viewing the script, it looks like below.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT] WITH CHECK AND CONSTRAINT [FK_PRODUCT_PRODUCT] FOREIGN KEY([ID_PRODUCT_PARENT]) REFERENCES [dbo].[PRODUCT] ([ID_PRODUCT])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PRODUCT] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_PRODUCT_PRODUCT]
GO
```

Comment: Well what does that foreign key look like? It is a foreign key to some table but from the name it is impossible to know what table.

Comment: Your script is dropping a default constraint, not the foreign key constraint referenced in the error message. Perhaps you need to query `sys.foreign_keys` and `sys.foreign_key_columns`.

Comment: script the create for this table and show us the scheme of this table and the create statement of that foreign key

Comment: i think the problem is that he's not generating the scripts, but that EF doesn't "see" that FK needs to be dropped. We need some experts here

Comment: @SeanLange - The ID_PRODUCT_PARENT has foreign key relationship with ID_PRODUCT column of same table PRODUCT , I have updated my post with how the Index query is looking like

Comment: @DanGuzman I have updated my post with how the constraint key syntax is looking like

Comment: @GuidoG I have updated my post with the create statement of that key, will it help ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to drop the column `ID_COLUMN_PARENT` you will need to first drop the foreign key constraint `FK_PRODUCT_PRODUCT`. You eluded to knowing this in the question. This requires two statements.

```
alter table PRODUCT drop constraint FK_PRODUCT_PRODUCT;
alter table PRODUCT drop column ID_PRODUCT_PARENT;
```

In your question you sound concerned this may cause issues. Not sure what issues it may cause but they would be logical issues with the application, not with the database.

Comment: We are trying to delete the column using entity frame work code first approach, not direct SQL commands.. the entity framework should generate the  SQL commands and execute those commands on the SQL database